# Decrease the space between title and toc in Quarto

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, pdf, titles, quarto

I am using Quarto to create a PDF. When I chose not to include the author and date, the distance between the title and table of contents did not shorten but left a vertical space. I have attempted modifications using LaTeX methods but did not work.
Here is the original setting:

```
---
title: "Supplemental Material 3: Preprocessed Effect Sizes from Invididual Source Data"
toc: true
format: pdf
editor: visual
---
```

[image: PDF output]

I would greatly appreciate any help on this question!

Comment: Generally, `\tableofcontents` uses `\section*`  to write `\contentsname`.  The easy solution is to put negative `\vspace` between the two.  Or you could replace or modify `\section`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
---
title: "Supplemental Material 3: Preprocessed Effect Sizes from Invididual Source Data"
toc: false
number-sections: true
format: pdf
include-in-header:
- text: \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}   
---

```{=latex}
\vspace{-2.5cm}
\tableofcontents{}
```

# Statements 

# Formulas
````

[image: mwe]

Note: Additions to the preamble as in Rmarkdown:

```
header-includes:
- \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
```

Also work, but afaik, is not documented for Quarto.